# what to do if a blind rabbit is found in the wild?

Tags: rabbits

Recently me and my Dad have seen the same wild rabbit, who appears to be blind, while on a bike ride in a similar place. The rabbit's eyelids are shut and it appears disorientated and nervous when wandering around. We live in the countryside so wild life is not unusual, however I'm wondering if something needs to be done for this little guy if seen again? My father seems to think this rabbit isn’t particularly old however I cannot vouch for this as neither of us are experts.

Answer (score 3):

If you find a wild animal that is hurt or ill you have to do an ethical choice:

- Do you want to let nature its go?
- Do you feel the need to do something for this animal?

There are some reasons for both points, for example "it is a human shaped surrounding, the humans have to care for the last animals there", or "there are so many of them and the hunting animals needs a meal too".

This decision you have to do alone.

If you choose to do something for the animal: You should inform yourself about stations who handle wild animals. There are everywhere vets or other organizations who care for wild animals and if it is possible after healing they will let go the animal back to the wild.

Next step will be to come in contact with them and ask them about the next steps to do. For example they could ask you to bring the animal to the station, or they decide to pick it up theirself. Same it could be they give you advice how to care for the animal at your home too.

Get in contact with a station handling wild animals and ask for advice for your own case.